# How to make indices (math mode super- and sub-script) uniform size?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I use Latex primarily to write tensor algebra, typically with a variety of latin and greek indices depending on the context. Normally this is fine, but I have noticed that occasionally some of the character heights (I assume) are different enough to be noticeable. In particular, when we have a pair of indices that are "(anti)symmetrised", which means we include a () or [] with the indices. Then the brackets are clearly miss-aligned. Here is an illustration of a minimal setup:

```
A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}
```

I have tried to find a solution to this, but haven't come across anything

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You should add a phantom superscript to the second term, like `A_{\kappa]\nu}^{\mathstrut}`. (I was going to suggest the `tensor` package as I thought its recent versions dealt with this issue but apparently the problem is still there...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use luatex, you can play with `\mathscriptsmode`. See section 7.5.7 for what the different modes mean.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\mathscriptsmode 0
0: $A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\mathscriptsmode 1
1: $A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\mathscriptsmode 2
2: $A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\mathscriptsmode 3
3: $A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\mathscriptsmode 4
4: $A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\mathscriptsmode 5
5: $A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}$\par

\end{document}
```

Compiled with lualatex, this gives here this result:

[image: scripts in different modes]

**Small update**: Since it looks like (with the notation from the luatex manual) `s` and `d` are set to the same value in Latin Modern Math, we do not see any difference between case 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I therefore paste the result I get with the similar test file in ConTeXt, where `\Umathsubshiftdown` was altered a bit, to imitate the behavior of Computer Modern.

[image: same example with context]

Comment: It doesn't make a great deal of difference here, but if this were a real document, and these expressions embedded in continuous text, there's a real danger of a collision when what is done with line 0 is applied.  (I'm assuming that the subscript is made to appear as if it is not as low as it really is; I can't believe that the height of the first A in line 1 is decreased.)

Comment: Given that 0 looks like the first line, I thought it was the default. I agree it looks too close to line 1. (It does not look like that in ConTeXt.)

Comment: Yes this does seem like the easiest one and done fix. Though annoyingly I had a hard time compiling lualatex correctly with vimtex. I can compile it separately, just directly in the terminal and it works, just not as conveniently.

Comment: Although a bit off-topic here, I have a specific `latexmkrc` that I use with vimtex to compile lualatex projects. I can share it tomorrow if you're interested (not at the computer now, and too late...)

Answer (score 3):

A solution might be to use `\tensor` or `\indices` from the [`tensor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensor) package. I'm not sure the alignment is perfect but it's certainly better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
\(A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} A_{\kappa]\nu}\)

\(\tensor*{A}{^\rho_{\sigma[\lambda}}\tensor{A}{_{\kappa]\nu}}\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a specialized package to fix the vertical positioning issues, you could fix the issues yourself, either by providing "empty exponents" or, for the utmost in positioning fidelity, `\vphantom`, i.e, invisible instructions inside the exponent terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
A^{\rho}_{\sigma[\lambda} 
A_{\kappa]\nu} 
A^{}_{\kappa]\nu}
A^{\vphantom{\rho}}_{\kappa]\nu}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My only issue with this fix is its very manual, and my document is pretty big. plus typing out an extra 10-15 characters every time this crops up would be frustrating

Comment: @LilyKavanagh You can create a custom command for `A^{\vphantom{\rho}}` (or something shorter from the left, to generalize).